# Android sensor.getType() check sometimes incorrect

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, android-orientation

I need to get orientation values and I follow the common approach:

```
@Override
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    switch (event.sensor.getType()){
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            mGravity = event.values;
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            mGeomagnetic = event.values;
            break;
    }

    if (mGravity == mGeomagnetic){
        Log.w("Sensor", "Strange things happen!");
    }
}

public float[] getOrientation(){
    float orientation[] = new float[3];
    if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];
        if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic)) {
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            return orientation;
        } else {
            Log.w("Sensor", "getRotationMatrix() failed");
        }
    }
    return new float[]{0,0,0};
}
```

As you see, I've checked if two values stored separately equals. And I was forced to do this because **Strange things really happen**!

How could it be and how to avoid this? The check of event.sensor.getType() is sometimes incorrect. The logic does not work, what am I missing???

Here's some more intel. Switch statement works well, but the variables are mixed anyway.

[image]

Could it be that **event.values** contains old data??

UPD: If I understand correctly, the variables link to the same position in memory... What's wrong in here?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try copying the SensorEvent `values` field instead of keeping a reference.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I found that I did not initialize mGravity and mGeomagnetic;

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if(sensor.getType()==Sensors.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
{
..... 
}<p>
if()  //other sensor check
```

Instead of switch statements

Avoid using switch case in sensors. Worked for me!